# I develop on Windows and my production is on Linux, how can I do properly the docker-compose file?

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose

Actually I have something like that for my development environment on Windows 10 (not the entire file) :

```
db:
    image: mysql:5.6
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    environment:
      - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password"
      - "MYSQL_USER=root"
      - "MYSQL_PASSWORD=password"
      - "MYSQL_DATABASE=simtp"

engine:
    build: ./docker/engine/
    volumes:
        - "c:/working_directory/simtp:/var/www/docker:rw"
        - "c:/working_directory/simtp/docker/engine/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/custom.ini:ro"
    links:
        - "db:db"
    working_dir: "/var/www/simtp"
```

The problem is on Windows paths.
How can I do properly the thing? When I'll run docker-compose on production it will be sure that I'll receive an error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use relative paths in your docker-compose.yml:

```
db:
    image: mysql:5.6
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    environment:
      - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password"
      - "MYSQL_USER=root"
      - "MYSQL_PASSWORD=password"
      - "MYSQL_DATABASE=simtp"

engine:
    build: ./docker/engine/
    volumes:
        - "./:/var/www/docker:rw"
        - "./docker/engine/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/custom.ini:ro"
    links:
        - "db:db"
    working_dir: "/var/www/simtp"
```

Instruct them to put the docker-compose.yml file in `c:/working_directory/simtp` or where their  files are

Regards